# setTimeout Behaviour with two different statements

Tags: javascript, settimeout

```js
    setTimeout(()=> alert('hi'), 3000); 
    setTimeout(()=> alert('hello'), 5000);
```

I am really struggling hard understanding setTimeout method. In the above code, the first statement works correctly meaning, **it displays hi after 3 seconds**.

But the next statement **doesn't delay by 5seconds**. Why?
The second output is shown immediately after the first one without any dealy. Please explain the behaviour. Refer me some article to understand in detail.

Comment: Neither of your `setTimeout()` calls will delay at all, because you're **calling** `alert()` before `setTimeout()`.

Comment: and the point that the method call is missing an `e` (time*_e_*out not timout)

Comment: The dup is mistaken... it's not the same case.

Comment: To use function with parameter inside `setTimeout` use like this way `setTimeout(alert, 3000, 'hi'); `.

Comment: @thelostcause What you want is `setTimeout (() => (alert ('hi'), setTimeout (() => alert ('hello'))))`

Comment: "*The second output is shown immediately after the first one without any delay*" - only when you take more than 2s to confirm the first alert.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is working correct:

```js
console.log('start now:',new Date().toISOString());
setTimeout(()=> console.log('hi now:',new Date().toISOString()), 3000); // 3 seconds after starts
setTimeout(()=> console.log('hello now:', new Date().toISOString()), 5000); // 5 seconds after starts, 2 seconds after hi.
```